# How do I import an Android Wear activity class into a mobile activity class?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I used Android Studio to autogenerate an Android Wear project, which includes a *mobile* folder for the code that runs on the phone, and a *wear* folder for the code that runs on the watch. Both folders contain the same package name hierarchy.

In the *mobile* part of the project, I have an activity called **src/main/java/mypackage/MobileActivity.java**. In the *wear* part of the project, there is another activity called **src/main/java/mypackage/WearActivity.java**.

My problem is, when I try to create a wearable action on the mobile side (according to [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#SpecifyWearableOnlyActions)), I can't access the **WearActivity** class in MobileActivity.java:

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, WearActivity.class);
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Action wearableAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_launcher, getString(R.string.label_show_details), actionPendingIntent).build();
new WearableExtender().addAction(wearableAction))
```

*(Error: cannot find symbol class WearActivity)*

So my question is, how should I import WearActivity from the *wear* side of the project, into the *mobile* side of the project, so I can refer to it in the Intent I'm creating?

Comment: It seems I may have misunderstood how the Wearable Only Actions described in the linked documentation work. They're not supposed to launch an Activity on the wearable app, but an Activity on the mobile app instead. So the question that I'm asking is probably not answerable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not reference the WearActivity in the mobile app at all, but instead use *com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi* to send a message from the mobile app to the wear app. The wear app can then locally launch its own notification which includes the **WearActivity** action.

This is documented in https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html.